# Error in Connecting to JDBC ODBC driver in webapplication deployed on jboss

Tags: java, jdbc, web-applications, jndi, jboss5.x

I am trying to use sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver driver to connect to Database. Previously I was using thin driver. I installed ODAC, created DSN and its working fine from below main class. I am able to connect to database.

```
    private static Connection getConnection1(){

           try {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
           } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

           }
           Connection connection = null;
           try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                           "jdbc:odbc:dev", "usr","pswrd");
                System.out.println(connection);
           } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
           }


        return connection;
   }
```

Problem is, I have to use jdbc odbc driver to connect to database from my webapplication which is deployed on jboss server. Its throwing invalid database url excpetion. below is my jndi code.

```
    <xa-datasource>

    <jndi-name>is-orcl</jndi-name>

    <track-connection-by-tx>true</track-connection-by-tx>

    <isSameRM-override-value>false</isSameRM-override-value>

    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>

    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:odbc:dev</xa-datasource-property>

    <xa-datasource-property name="User">usr</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Password">pswrd</xa-datasource-property>

    </xa-datasource>
```

Comment: I created ansystem dsn with the name dev. U can check my main class its working fine so problem is with jboss configuration.

Comment: <xa-datasource-property name="User">user</xa-datasource-property>

Comment: yaar kehna kya chahte ho

Comment: There is a typo you have typed "usr" it should have been "user"

Comment: no, its my username and password for my database schema so its correct

Comment: connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                           "jdbc:odbc:dev", "user","pswrd"); Here y have you used "user" then?

Comment: You can't use the `OracleXADataSource` for an ODBC connection. It is only for `jdbc:oracle:...` connections.

Comment: Mark - what should I use? Can you please give me an example?

Comment: I am connecting to oracle database using jdbc odbc driver

Comment: You should use the Oracle JDBC driver and a suitable Oracle connection string, not the JDBC ODBC bridge.